# Scraping emails with PHP

Tags: php, email, imap, data-extraction

I have a script which should scrap selected email from the inbox. Everything works except BODY. Subject, date, sender and etc.. were scraped without problems but the body were returned like this:

> VG9kYXkncyBGcmVlIGFuZCBCYXJnYWluIEJvb2tzCgpVcGRhdGUgUHJlZmVyZW5jZXM6ICBodHRw
>   Oi8vd3d3LmJvb2tnb3JpbGxhLmNvbS9wcmVmZXJlbmNlcz9oPTZjNTgxNDEyYjkzMTdiMWZlNjc1
>   ZDcwNDFjODJhYTc5Ckludml0ZSBGcmllbmRzOiBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJvb2tnb3JpbGxhLmNvbS9p
>   bnZpdGU/aD02YzU4MTQxMmI5MzE3YjFmZTY3NWQ3MDQxYzgyYWE3OQpVbnN1YnNjcmliZTogaHR0
>   cDovL3d3dy5ib29rZ29yaWxsYS5jb20vdW5zdWJzY3JpYmU/aD02YzU4MTQxMmI5MzE3YjFmZTY3
>   NWQ3MDQxYzgyYWE3OQoKQWxsIHByaWNlcyB3ZXJlIHZlcmlmaWVkIGJ5IEJvb2tHb3JpbGxhIHBy
>   aW9yIHRvIHRoaXMgZW1haWwgYmVpbmcgc2VudCwgYnV0IHByaWNlcyBtYXkgY2hhbmdlIHdpdGhv
>   dXQgbm90aWNlIHNvIHBsZWFzZSB2ZXJpZnkgdGhhdCB0aGUgYm9vayBpcyBzdGlsbCBmcmVlIG9y
>   IGJhcmdhaW4gcHJpY2VkIGJlZm9yZSBjb25maXJtaW5nIHlvdXIgb3JkZXIuIFNvbWUgYm9va3Mg
>   bWF5IG5vdCBiZSBmcmVlIG91dHNpZGUgdGhlIFVuaXRlZCBTdGF0ZXMuIFdlIHdlbGNvbWUgeW91
>   ciBmZWVkYmFjaywgc28gcGxlYXNlIHJlcGx5IHRvIHRoaXMgZW1haWwgaWYgeW91IGhhdmUgYW55
>   IGNvbW1lbnRzIG9yIHN1Z2dlc3Rpb25zIHlvdSB3b3VsZCBsaWtlIHRvIHNoYXJlIHdpdGggdXMu
>   CgoKCi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0t
>   LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0NCg0KRG9uJ3Qg
>   bWlzcyB0aGlzIEJFU1QgUFJJQ0UgRVZFUiBvbiBEZWJiaWUgTWFjb21iZXIncyBjbGFzc2ljIERl
>   Y2VtYmVyIDIwMTMgcmVsZWFzZSE8YnIgLz48YnIgLz5GcmllbmRzLS1BbmQgVGhlbiBTb21lPGJy
>   IC8+KERlYmJpZSBNYWNvbWJlciBDbGFzc2ljcykNCkJ5IERlYmJpZSBNYWNvbWJlcjxiciAvPjxi
>   ciAvPjY3JSBQcmljZSBDdXQgVGhpcyBXZWVrIQ0KDQoqKioqKiBTVEFSUkVEIFRJVExFICoqKioq
>   CgogT25lIG9mIGFjY2xhaW1lZCBhdXRob3IgRGViYmllIE1hY29tYmVy4oCZcyBjbGFzc2ljIG5v
>   dmVscywgdGhpcyB0ZW5kZXIgc3Rvcnkgb2YgdHdvIHBlb3BsZSBkYXJpbmcgdG8gYmUgbW9yZSB0
>   aGFuIOKAnGp1c3QgZnJpZW5kc+KAnSBpcyBhdmFpbGFibGUgZm9yIHRoZSBmaXJzdCB0aW1lIGlu
>   IHRoZSBLaW5kbGUgc3RvcmUhDQoNClRvZGF5J3MgQmFyZ2FpbiBQcmljZTogJDAuOTkNCg0KR2V0
>   IEl0IE5vdw0KaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ib29rZ29yaWxsYS5jb20vbGluaz9sPWh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZ

And I have no idea why is it? This is a code I'm using:

```
$inbox_details = $this->email_main->getInboxDetails($data['inbox_id']); // select inbox data by inbox id
    $message_id = $inbox_details['last_sended_email_id'] + 1;

    $imap = imap_open('{'. $data['inbox_data']['inbox_server'] .'}INBOX', ''. $data['inbox_data']['inbox_email'] .'', ''. $data['inbox_data']['inbox_password'] .''); 
    if (!$imap)
        $this->email_main->insertError(imap_last_error(), $data['inbox_data']['id']);

    $header = imap_header($imap, $message_id);
    $message = array(
        'subject' => $header->subject,
        'fromname' => $header->fromaddress,
        'fromaddress' => $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host,
        'toaddress' => $header->toaddress,
        'date' => $header->date,
        'timestamp' => $header->udate,
        'body' => imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($imap, $message_id, 2)), // $message_id = 1
    );
```

any ideas folks?

Comment: Looks to be base64, use the [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) method to get your info.

Comment: the decoded texts supplies links to modify settings for bests@mediahear.co.uk account on bookGorilla ... FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content is encoded in base64.

```
 base64_decode($content);
```

Will decode it :)

Edit:
Decoded with http://www.base64decode.org/ to get 'Today's Free and Bargain Books'

Comment: and You just made my friday! Thanks ;)

Comment: No problem good sir. Do not forget to mark the question as answered so it can be seen as closed.

Comment: +1 - Now I know where to get me some "Free Bargain Books" ;-)

Comment: Bwahahahah so true. Maybe OP didn't actually have any problems but just a genius advertising campaign based on appeasing the score hungry needs of SO users :)

Comment: this can be true, all the time script worked fine and only now it came with problems. First problem with that encoding now I have problem to get parsed details.

Comment: If you are having further problems simply create another question. Plenty of SO people online to help - and they are ridiculously friendly.